# Change background color in a google timeline chart row

Tags: charts, google-visualization

Refer: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline#a-simple-example

[image]

In the above chart, alternate rows have a background color.
Adams is gray whereas Washington and Jefferson are white.
I want to color the background based on one of the data values related to the row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are no standard options to change the background color of the row.

but the color can be changed manually, on the chart's `'ready'` event.

the background rows will be drawn using `<rect>` elements.
when the event fires, find the elements by testing the following attributes.

`x` - all will have a value of zero --> `x="0"`
`stroke` - only the overall background `<rect>` will have a stroke attribute other than `"none"`

then set the `fill` attribute to the color of your choice.

```
  // make sure rect is a background row
  if ((rect.getAttribute('x') === '0') && (rect.getAttribute('stroke') === 'none')) {
    // determine existing color
    if (rect.getAttribute('fill') === '#ffffff') {
      rect.setAttribute('fill', 'cyan');
    } else {
      rect.setAttribute('fill', 'magenta');
    }
  }
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['timeline']
}).then(function () {
  var container = document.getElementById('chart');
  var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
  var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

  dataTable.addColumn({type: 'string', id: 'President'});
  dataTable.addColumn({type: 'date', id: 'Start'});
  dataTable.addColumn({type: 'date', id: 'End'});
  dataTable.addRows([
    ['Washington', new Date(1789, 3, 30), new Date(1797, 2, 4)],
    ['Adams',      new Date(1797, 2, 4),  new Date(1801, 2, 4)],
    ['Jefferson',  new Date(1801, 2, 4),  new Date(1809, 2, 4)]
  ]);

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    var rects = container.getElementsByTagName('rect');
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(rects, function(rect) {
      // make sure rect is a background row
      if ((rect.getAttribute('x') === '0') && (rect.getAttribute('stroke') === 'none')) {
        // determine existing color
        if (rect.getAttribute('fill') === '#ffffff') {
          rect.setAttribute('fill', 'cyan');
        } else {
          rect.setAttribute('fill', 'magenta');
        }
      }
    });
  });

  chart.draw(dataTable);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to do change background color when we are using the timeline of google chart inside our React component?